# Removing Timezone for DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am trying to parse a string into a datetime with the following format:

[Day],[Date] [Month] [Year] [Time][am/pm] [timezone] (example:)

"Thursday, 1 Dec 2011 08:30pm EST"

I've done this using a DateTime.ParseExact with the format("dddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mmtt"). However the timzone is giving me an issue. There is no code for reading the timezone written in that manner. I don't care about the timezone anyway, so I want to either strip it out or read it - as long as the parsexact will work.

One way of removing it is to actually remove it from the string (using .Replace) - however I don't know how many different timezones the source will produce, and anyway I think a long line of replace looks ugly and error-prone.

So is there a way of either removing it, or reading it (and then I can ignore it) ?

Comment: If a time zone is always present, you can cut the string at the last space, and parse everything else.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight
Hmm, that's a very good idea. If there is a cleaner way of doing it I'll prefer that, but that's otherwise a good solution.

Comment: Do you really want to ignore it ? It would be more relevant in case you could Replace the EST with the differences (Ohh my god day light savings) and then parse.

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/

Comment: @V4Vendetta
I only care about the actually date, and the chance of losing a day due to timezone differences is small enough that it won't matter. The thing is that its not just EST - it could be something else, which is why I can't just run a simple replace.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I finally went with your solution. If you repost that as an Answer I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: IF you have a limited number of possible timezones, then you could use the "string[] formats" overload. That way it will keep any possible changes to day due to timezone as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scan the string for spaces, and cut everything after the fifth space. If there are only four spaces, keep the entire string (this means that there is no timezone).

*This answer has been edited after a comment by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon).*

Comment: It would probably be better to cut at the 5th space rather than at the last one. You never know when the timezone name might somehow gain a human-readable component that contains spaces.

Comment: @Jon You are right, thanks for an excellent suggestion: cutting at the fifth space (if it exists) would work even if the timezone is not present!

Comment: (I used "LastIndexOf(' ')" instead. Given how horribly sensitive ParseExact is, if there were any changes whatsoever to anything it'd break anyway.

Comment: @Aabela: In .NET 4, this could be as simple as `String.Join(" ", "Thursday, 1 Dec 2011 08:30pm EST".Split(' ').Take(5))`.