# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 26

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am working on XML feed from RSS, i thinking of sorting the feed by their published date and time. Since different RSS feeds are being taken, they have different data and time formats.

for example

```
Sat, 23 Mar 2013 23:19:54 GMT
Sat, 23 Mar 2013 23:19:54 EDT
Sat, 23 Mar 2013 23:19:54 -0400
```

I want to convert them in local time and then sort them.

```
  var rssFeed = from el in doc.Elements("rss").Elements("channel").Elements("item")
  select new
  {
       Title = el.Element("title").Value,
       Link = el.Element("link").Value,
       Description = el.Element("description").Value,
       PubDate = DateTime.Parse(el.Element("pubDate").Value, null,
                        DateTimeStyles.None)            
  };
```

Please let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be your `DateTime` string is not in correct format to be parsed.

use this instead:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(el.Element("pubDate").Value,
                                  "ddd, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss",null);
```

and pass your appropriate format to get your date.

you will have to get rid of that TimeZone portion in the end.

read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699440/removing-timezone-for-datetime-parseexact) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527706/how-do-i-format-datetime-or-timezone-timezoneinfo-to-display-three-letters)